# JavaScript - What is correct way for replace "\" charcter with "/" in RegExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I defined a function in JavaScript that replace all `-`, `_`, `@`, `#`, `$` and `\` (they are possible separators) with `/` (valid separator).

My goal is any string like `"1394_ib_01#13568"` convert to `"1394/ib/01/13568"`

```
function replaceCharacters(input) {

    pattern_string = "-|_|@|#|$|\u005C";      // using character Unicode
    //pattern_string = "-|_|@|#|$|\";         // using original character
    //pattern_string = "-|_|@|#|$|\\";        // using "\\"
    //pattern_string = "\|-|_|@|#|$";         // reposition in middle or start of string
    pattern = new RegExp(pattern_string, "gi");

    input = input.replace(pattern, "/");
    return input;
}
```

My problem is when a string with `\` character send to function result is not valid.

I tried use Unicode of `\` in define pattern, Or use `\\\` instead of it. Also I replaced position of it in pattern string. But in any of this situation, problem wasn't solved and browser return invalid result or different error such as:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated parenthetical    ---> in using "\u005C"
SyntaxError: \ at end of pattern           ---> in using "\\"
Invalid Result: broken result in 2 Line or replace with undefined character based on input string (the character after "\" determine result)
                        ---> in reposition it in middle or start of pattern string
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of input and an example of what you expect as a result??
Isn't clear what you pass to the *replaceCharacters* function...

ex: 
input: 'hello world';
output: 'goodbye world'

Comment: Dear Mr/Mrs [@Hitmands](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4099454/hitmands), I send `"categoryname#objectname@1394\02\01-codeID"` send to function. I expect function returns `"categoryname/objectname/1394/02/01/codeID"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var pattern_string = "-|_|@|#|\\$|\\\\";
```

You have to escape the slash once for the pattern, so it'll try to match the literal character:

```
\\
```

Then, escape each slash again for the string literal:

```
"\\\\"
```

Also note that I added an escape for the `$`. To match a dollar sign literally, it'll needs to be escaped as well, since it normally represents an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for the "end of the line/string."

---

You can also use a [Regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to avoid the string, using only the escape sequences necessary for the pattern:

```
var pattern = /-|_|@|#|\$|\\/gi;
```

And, as you're matching only single characters, you can use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) instead of [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
var pattern = /[-_@#\$\\]/gi;
```

(Just be careful with the placement of the `-` here. It's fine as the first character in the class, but can represent a range of characters when placed in the middle. You can also escape it to ensure it doesn't represent a range.)

Comment: Mr [@Jonathan Lonowski](http://stackoverflow.com/users/15031/jonathan-lonowski), thank you for your attention.

I replaced your solution by my code. And call function with `"categoryname#objectname@1394\02\01-codeID"` again. I expect function returns `"categoryname/objectname/1394/02/01/codeID"`. But result is `"categoryname/objectname/1394/codeID
"
`

Comment: My fault is I send string `categoryname#objectname@1394\02\01-codeID`, that is wrong input.
In JavaScript, when I want call function with direct parameter string, I have to send `categoryname#objectname@1394\\02\\01-codeID` to function. Because first `'\'` means next character is special character. Therefore sequence of `'\\'` in my input string means only one `'\'`.